# Laravel query by date and time

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Query by date and time.

I have table with field and sample data

```
Schedule
 --date_start     = 2019-05-01  
 --date_end       = 2019-06-30
 --time_start     = 08:00:00
 --time_end       = 10:00:00
```

My question is can I query it by doing select date by (current_date) if current_date is in range or in between the date_start and date end. the same also in time if time is in range

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with something like this

```
$current = Schedule::whereDate('start_date', '<=', today())
    ->whereDate('end_date', '>=', today())
    ->whereTime('start_time', '<=', now())
    ->whereTime('end_time', '>=', now())
    ->get();
```

`$current` will be the DB records that are for now.

[More information at the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses)